# Yii2 - Make Form Validator For URL Type To Skip "http://" in the start

Tags: yii2

This is how my yii2 model looks like:-

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;


class UrlForm extends Model
{
    public $url;
    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [            
            [['url'], 'required'],
            ['url', 'url'],            
        ];
    }

}
```

I want it to approve the url if use has not written 'http://' in the start.

**Example:-**

`stackoverflow.com` should work fine.

`http://stackoverflow.com` should work fine.

**Current Status:-**

`stackoverflow.com` not accepted.

`http://stackoverflow.com` is accepted..

Comment: You probably meant `http://` in your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add 'defaultScheme' => 'http' to your validation rule, so

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [            
            [['url'], 'required'],
            ['url', 'url', 'defaultScheme' => 'http'],            
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Once again thanks Joe :) ... you have helped me a lot in learning Yii2.

Answer (score 0):

Test if the parameter URL (most likely as a string) contains `http://` at the beginning; `if (doesntcontainHTTP){addHttpToURL();}`

Example:

```
class UrlForm extends Model
{
    public $url;
    /**
     * @add "http://" to the url in here
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        /**
         * @Place the if statement here
         */
        return [            
            [['url'], 'required'],
            ['url', 'url'],            
        ];
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, that's obvious logic, but my problem is that I don't know where to place this logic in yii2?